# Wsgi single thread configuration on a multi-threaded apache server

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi, single-threaded

```
WSGIDaemonProcess <user> processes=5 threads=1 python-home=/path/to

WSGIProcessGroup <user>
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

My application uses Gdal which is not thread safe. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/deployment/) suggests using wsgi with `threads=1`. If the apache configuration is using a threaded `mpm-worker` will `threads=1` guarantee thread safety?

Apache settings:

```
KeepAlive Off
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ServerLimit 1
StartServers 1
MaxRequestWorkers 5
MinSpareThreads 1
MaxSpareThreads 3
ThreadsPerChild 5
```

---

A [complementary quote](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/modwsgi/6Px1LSBftyk/U4CqFvtFRDMJ) to the accepted answer is the following:

```
StartServers          2
ThreadsPerChild      25
WSGIDaemonProcess processes=1 threads=15
```

> In the case of the WSGI application, the Apache child worker processes
>   only act as a proxy, forwarding the requests across to the mod_wsgi
>   daemon mode process(es) for handling.
>
> Thus, with 2 Apache child worker processes, maximum number of
>   connections is 50 (where each has 25 threads). These Apache child
>   worker processes accept connections for both static file requests and
>   dynamic requests which are then proxied across to the mod_wsgi daemon
>   mode process. With only a single mod_wsgi daemon mode process, the
>   WSGI application itself will be able to handle 15 concurrent requests.
>
> If there are requests being handled by mod_wsgi daemon mode process,
>   because the Apache child worker processes is proxying the requests and
>   responses, a thread is still consumed for the life of the request in
>   the Apache child worker processes. The 35 (50-15) additional threads
>   in Apache child worker processes would still be available for handling
>   static requests, keep alive connections and acting as a buffering
>   mechanism for pending dynamic requests against WSGI application. The
>   latter particularly useful for slow clients as apache child worker
>   processes will not forward request onto mod_wsgi daemon process until
>   full request information available.
>
> Note that just because mod_wsgi daemon mode process can only handle 15
>   concurrent requests doesn't mean that it can only handle that many
>   requests per second. How many requests per second is going to be
>   dictated by how slow your application is and what contention there is
>   on shared resources. The latter have an impact on whether operations
>   need to be serialised.
>
> Overall, just think of mod_wsgi daemon mode as being similar to using
>   mod_proxy in front of a separate back end web server. In this case
>   though mod_wsgi has created the daemon processes and is managing them
>   on your behalf.
>
> Graham Dumpleton

Comment: Thumbs up to including the quote, extremely valuable info that should have been more clearly documented in mod_wsgi's page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using mod_wsgi daemon mode, Python requests are handled in processes separate to Apache child worker processes, so yes, using `threads=1` will in that case guarantee thread safety.

For more information on how processes and threading in mod_wsgi works read the documentation about it:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/processes-and-threading.html

You might also watch:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGleKfigMsk